# AJAX Call to PHP Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function showEditDialog(regID){
        $.post("getGiftDetail.php", 
                {reg_id: regID },
                function(data) {});

}
```

I am calling "getGiftDetail.php" with Ajax,, but this php file is not getting called. Please help me! Why isn't this working?

Comment: You could try using the full URL to `getGiftDetail.php`

Comment: How do you know it doesn't get called? What does your browser's network debug tool say?

Comment: You need to give us the error(s) you are getting.

Comment: Have you tried using Chrome's dev-tools or Firebug to check the network panel? Look at the XHR requests.

Comment: You have an empty anonymous function in the callback. Try `alert(data);` in the callback to see if a response is returned.

Answer (score -2):

index.html

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        function showEditDialog(regID){
            $.post("getGiftDetail.php", {reg_id: regID }, function(data) {});
        }
        showEditDialog(5);
    });
</script>
```

And do not forget to include jquery and use firebug/developers console